# Python regular expression string search to return start index

Tags: python, string, search

Apologies if this has already been asked.  Is there a way in Python 3x to search for a whole word in a string and return its starting index?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any whole word or a specific word?

Comment: See the documentation for [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with a regex and [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "rebar bar barbed"
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\bbar\b")
>>> for match in regex.finditer(s):
...     print(match.group(), match.start(), match.end())
...
bar 6 9
```

The `\b` anchors make sure that only entire words can match. If you're dealing with non-ASCII words, use `re.UNICODE` to compile the regex, otherwise `\b` won't work as expected, at least not in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first occurrence, you can use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.finditer) and next.

```
s =  "foo  bar foobar"
import re

m = next(re.finditer(r"\bfoobar\b",s),"")
if m:
   print(m.start())
```

Or as @Tim Pietzcker commented use `re.search`:

```
import re
m = re.search(r"\bfoobar\b",s)
if m:
    print(m.start())
```

Comment: If you just want the first occurrence, just use `re.search()`.